# Updating collection property in explicit model binding VS implicit model binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-binding

I have an entity model that has a collection property (many-to-many relationship) of Users signed up for the application.
in the Edit view I used implicit model binding to edit task object with the single properties (`Title`, `DueDate`, etc..) and `Users` (checkboxes) :

```
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Description,DueDate,Status")] UserTask task, string[] asndUsers/*users IDs*/)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            task.Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
            if (asndUsers != null)
            {
                foreach (var userId in asndUsers)
                {
                    var user = context.Users.Find(userId);
                    task.Users.Add(user);
                }
            }
            context.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(task);
    }
```

but this didn't work, the single properties was updated but the Users couldn't be updated.

I then used the explicit model binding

```
var task = context.Tasks.Include(t => t.Users).SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
task.Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    foreach (var userId in asndUsers)
    {
        var user = context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == userId);
        task.Users.Add(user);
    }
if (TryUpdateModel(task, "", new string[] { "Title", "Description", "DueDate", "Status" }))
{
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

it works, but have no idea what it did that implicit binding didn't